# Phonebook in php without using MySQL

Tags: php

I just wanted to create a simple phonebook using php...I used the following code....but one entry overwrites another plz help...I want to do this without using MySQL

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
{
    $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['views']=1;

    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Phonebook</title>
</head>

<body>


<form action="index1.php" method="post" style="border:thin">
Name: <input type="text" name="varname" style="border:dotted" />
<br/>
Roll Number:<input type="text" name="varroll" style="border:dotted" />
<br />
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="varno" style="border:dotted" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /><br/>
</form>
<?php


$test1[$_SESSION['views']]=$_POST['varname'];
$test2[$_SESSION['views']]=$_POST['varroll'];
$test3[$_SESSION['views']]=$_POST['varno'];
for($j=1;$j<=$_SESSION['views'];$j++)
{

echo $test1[$j]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$test2[$j]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$test3[$j];}
echo "<br/>";
echo "No. of page views=".$_SESSION['views'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice username <Frustrated Coder >

Comment: $_SESSION is temporary storage, and is not even shared between users. You'll need to use either MySQL, store it in files, or use one of the many, many databases available. Is there some reason why you don't want to use MySQL?

Comment: Are you against using MySQL specifically? Or do you need to avoid using an RDBMS for some reason? Is file-based persistance acceptable? In short: What is the problem you are looking for help with solving?

Answer (score 1):

You could write it to a text file with | seperating each value or you could use an ini or xml file

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just use $_SESSION, as it will be emptied when the user closes the browser.

Best to do something like this (sample untested code)

```
//loading
$data = unserialize( file_get_contents( 'mydata.txt' ) );
//editing
$entry = array();
$entry['roll']=$_POST['varroll'];
$entry['name']=$_POST['varname'];
$data[] = $entry;
//saving
file_put_contents( 'mydata.txt', serialize($data) );
```

Comment: I just want to explore PHP.....Ya I want to input entries till browser is running...Else I can use a cookie using set_cookie function...thats not an issue...

Comment: as you prefer :) but you may want to clarify your question then. Go ahead with experimentation and post the precise problem you get. It is really NOT clear what your current problem is.

Comment: <p> Where do I "echo" in your script...Your code supposedly overwrites the data though it is successful in saving it in a notepad. I wish to display all entries on the webpage itself along with the new entry. Thanks any way for help :P </p>

Comment: Yes, it is just sample code, showing how to load and how to save. Up to you do create the necessary IFs. Good work !